# Regex expression in mapinfo sql to remove special character

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic, regular-expression

Is there a way to clean the values in the column to just have A-Z 0-9 and _ ?

In python/regex I run

```
def Alphanumeric(string):
 import re
 clean_string=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9‌​_]', '', string)
 return clean_string
```

I need to do this in Mapinfo as an update column. I see something close in http://nyalldawson.net/2013/05/regular-expressions-in-mapbasic/ and am in the process of exploring this.

Additionally, I know I can run InStr() for each of these values but I am hoping for a one-liner.

Comment: In general you can build your own DLL with .NET (e.g. free MS Visual Studio Community Edition) having almost any function. Check chapter 12 - Integrated Mapping in [MapBasic Documentation](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/16.0/MapBasicUserGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for "mapbasic regex" and found what looks to be what you may need posted in the [nyalldawson.net](http://nyalldawson.net/2013/05/regular-expressions-in-mapbasic/) blog:

> If you’re not familiar with regular expressions, they’re an extremely
>   powerful tool for string manipulation. They can be somewhat daunting
>   at first, but with a bit of practice they’ll open up all kinds of
>   string processing which would otherwise be extremely convoluted or
>   impossible.
>
> Up until now there’s been no way of using the beauty of regular
>   expressions within MapInfo. Now, with MbRegEx, all their mighty power
>   can be fully utilised within your MapBasic scripts!

Comment: Good find.  I didn't think there was a way to do regex in MapInfo.

Comment: Thanks -yes I added http://nyalldawson.net/2013/05/regular-expressions-in-mapbasic/ to my question earlier -the issue is it's in mapbasic. I also just found http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-in-mapbasic which may work by creating an mbx that the wor calls. Wish MI used python :-)

Comment: Just came across this again. It's been upgraded to 64 bit now - https://community.pitneybowes.com/communities/communityhome/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=a92a0fcd-5348-4eae-aa93-a47d5a1e6bbe&CommunityKey=3c2aca7a-c3ae-4602-a142-9ee956769d55&tab=digestviewer#bma92a0fcd-5348-4eae-aa93-a47d5a1e6bbe